# Howto use variable attribute for Jquery lightbox plugin

Tags: jquery, attributes, variables, lightbox

I try to implement the JQuery Lightbox plugin with dynamic grouped of images (grouped in image popup), but i can not find the clue for popup grouped images.

Can someone tell me what i'm doing wrong?

**HTML**

```
<a href="pic1.jpg" class="pic" rel="lightbox1"><img src="pic1.jpg"/></a>
<a href="pic2.jpg" class="pic" rel="lightbox1"><img src="pic2.jpg"/></a>

<a href="pic3.jpg" class="pic" rel="lightbox2"><img src="pic3.jpg"/></a>
<a href="pic4.jpg" class="pic" rel="lightbox2"><img src="pic4.jpg"/></a>

<a href="pic5.jpg" class="pic" rel="lightbox3"><img src="pic5.jpg"/></a>
<a href="pic6.jpg" class="pic" rel="lightbox3"><img src="pic6.jpg"/></a>
```

**JQUERY**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {    
  $('a.pic').live('click', function() {
      var relvalue = $(this).attr('rel');
      $("a[rel="+relvalue+"]").lightBox();
  });
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: Which lightbox plugin are you using?

Comment: I'm using the JQuery Lightbox Plugin 0.5 by  Leandro Vieira
http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try this?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {    
  $('a.pic').lightBox();
});
```

I assumed you are using [krewenki's jquery-lightbox](http://github.com/krewenki/jquery-lightbox/). With `$('a.pic').lightBox();` you give to **a** elements the lightbox ability and with rel attributes on **a** elements you're grouping them.

Comment: Ok, i use another plugin as wrote in the comment above, but i think the jQuery-Lightbox from Warren Krewenki is easier and includes the possibility to group by the "rel" attribute. 

Thanks for the tip !